# How to add where condition clause dynamically in mySql Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
where  

  b.deviceId=device_id_U 

  and( 
  CONCAT('%',COALESCE(device_id_U,''),'%') and
   b.searchTerm like
   CONCAT('%',COALESCE(search_term,''),'%') and  
   b.deviceName like
  CONCAT('%',COALESCE(device_name,''),'%') and
   b.deviceNumber    like
  CONCAT('%',COALESCE(device_Number,''),'%') and
  b.os like 
  CONCAT('%',COALESCE(device_os,''),'%') and
  b.deviceWorkingStatus like
  CONCAT('%',COALESCE(device_workingstatus_U,''),'%') and
  b.status like
  CONCAT('%',COALESCE(device_status_U,''),'%') )   

 ;
 end if;

END
```

This is my Procedure  i want when i pass device_id null then it should  ignore where condition with device id and if give device_id value then it should search device id wise please tell me how add dynamically where condition so that i can solve this issue i am facing problem to add where clause dynamically

Comment: can you please format your code and can you please post onlly the relevent bits of code

Comment: i have updated please check my issue now

Comment: `WHERE (@PARAM IS NULL OR @PARAM = ID)`

Comment: `...IFNULL(@PARAM,ID) LIKE ID...`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with inversion of @FDavidov's idea

```
where  b.deviceId= IFNULL(device_id_U , b.deviceId)
```